# I can't figure out how to feed a Placeholder by data from matlab

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a simple feed forward network. However, I can't figure out how to feed a Placeholder by data from matlab. This example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as scio
import math

# # create data
train_input=scio.loadmat('/Users/liutianyuan/Desktop/image_restore/data/input_for_tensor.mat')
train_output=scio.loadmat('/Users/liutianyuan/Desktop/image_restore/data/output_for_tensor.mat')
x_data=np.float32(train_input['input_for_tensor'])
y_data=np.float32(train_output['output_for_tensor'])

print x_data.shape
print y_data.shape
## create tensorflow structure start ###
def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, activation_function=None):
    Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([in_size,out_size], -4.0*math.sqrt(6.0/(in_size+out_size)), 4.0*math.sqrt(6.0/(in_size+out_size))))
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]))
    Wx_plus_b = tf.matmul(inputs, Weights) + biases
    if activation_function is None:
        outputs = Wx_plus_b
    else:
        outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b)
    return outputs

xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 256])
ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1024])
y= add_layer(xs, 256, 1024, activation_function=None)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - ys))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
### create tensorflow structure end ###

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)  

for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
       print(step, sess.run(loss,feed_dict={xs: x_data, ys: y_data}))
```

**Gives me the following error:**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/liutianyuan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/easycode.py

(1, 256)

(1, 1024)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liutianyuan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/easycode.py", line 46, in <module>
    sess.run(train)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 340, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 637, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 659, in _do_call
    e.code)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: **You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float**
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'Placeholder', defined at:

  File "/Users/liutianyuan/PycharmProjects/untitled1/easycode.py", line 30, in <module>
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 256])

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 762, in placeholder
    name=name)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 976, in _placeholder
    name=name)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2154, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1154, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I have checked both the type and shape of x_data and y_data, it seams they are corret. So i have no ideal where goes wrong.

Comment: It looks good. Can you try: `sess.run(loss,feed_dict={xs: tf.cast(x_data, tf.float32), ys: tf.cast(y_data, tf.float32)}`?

Comment: Thanks, but it still can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `train` operation depends on the placeholders `xs` and `ys`, so you must feed values for those placeholders when you call `sess.run(train)`.

A common way to do this is to divide your input data into mini-batches:

```
BATCH_SIZE = ...
for step in range(201):
    # N.B. You'll need extra code to handle the cases where start_index and/or end_index
    # wrap around the end of x_data and y_data.
    start_index = step * BATCH_SIZE
    end_index = (step + 1) * BATCH_SIZE
    start_index = sess.run(train, {xs: x_data[start_index:end_index,:],
                                   ys: y_data[start_index:end_index,:]})
```

The code in the example is just to get you started. For a more flexible way of generating data for feeding, see the [MNIST dataset example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L160) in the `tf.learn` codebase.

Comment: Thanks, but I  wrote a simple program just to learn the use of tensorflow, so there is only one piece of input data.

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I didn't understand what you meant, but after I  chew over your answer, I find it really works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mrry and the problem has been solved. It turns out that I miss the feed_dict part at sess.run(train). The right program is:

```
for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train,feed_dict={xs: x_data, ys: y_data})
    if step % 20 == 0:
       print(step, sess.run(loss,feed_dict={xs: x_data, ys: y_data}))
```